# Octave/Matlab: Efficient calc of Frobenius inner product?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have two matrices A and B and what I want to get is:

```
trace(A*B)
```

If I'm not mistaken this is called [Frobenius inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_product#Frobenius_inner_product).

My concern here is about efficiency. I'm just afraid that this strait-forward approach will first do the whole multiplication (my matrices are thousands of rows/cols) and only then take the trace of the product, while the operation I really need is much simplier. Is there a function or a syntax to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct...summing the element-wise products will be quicker:

```
n = 1000

A = randn(n);
B = randn(n);

tic
sum(sum(A .* B));
toc

tic
sum(diag(A * B'));
toc
```

```or-tag-here
Elapsed time is 0.010015 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.130514 seconds.
```

Comment: @izhak - an even better solution uses vector product. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16766221/1714410) along with run times.

Answer (score 2):

`sum(sum(A.*B))` avoids doing the full matrix multiplication

Answer (score 1):

How about using vector multiplication?

```
(A(:)')*B(:)
```

---

#### Run time check

Comparing four options with `A` and `B` of size 1000-by-1000:
1. vector inner product: `A(:)'*B(:)` (this answer) took **only `0.0011 sec`**.
2. Using element wise multiplication `sum(sum(A.*B))` ([John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8031814/1714410)'s answer) took `0.0035 sec`.
3. Trace `trace(A*B')` (proposed by OP) took `0.054 sec`.
4. Sum of diagonal `sum(diag(A*B'))` (option rejected by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8031814/1714410)) took  `0.055 sec`.

Take home message: Matlab is extremely efficient when it comes to matrix/vector product. Using vector inner product is **x3 times faster** even than the efficient element-wise multiplication solution.

---

**Benchmark code**
Code used to provide the run time checks

```
t=zeros(1,4);
n=1000; % size of matrices
it=100; % average results over XX trails
for ii=1:it, 
    % random inputs
    A=rand(n);
    B=rand(n); 
    % John's rejected solution
    tic; 
    n1=sum(diag(A*B'));
    t(1)=t(1)+toc;
    % element-wise solution
    tic;
    n2=sum(sum(A.*B));
    t(2)=t(2)+toc;
    % MOST efficient solution - using vector product
    tic;
    n3=A(:)'*B(:);
    t(3)=t(3)+toc;
    % using trace
    tic;
    n4=trace(A*B');
    t(4)=t(4)+toc;
    % make sure everything is correct
    assert(abs(n1-n2)<1e-8 && abs(n3-n4)<1e-8 && abs(n1-n4)<1e-8);
end;
t./it
```

You can now run this benchmark in a [click](http://ideone.com/C89OO8).